# How to bring role based view with UI Router in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, spring, angular-ui-router

I am developing a SPA (Single Page Application) with Angular JS and using "UI Router" for routing and using Spring MVC framework for back-end.

I would like to bring the user role based view in the application as we have different user roles in application.

What is the best way to do this?

Is there any way to retrieve the user role from server check it in the ui route before state changes?

Comment: Consider controlling menu according to role rather then state. If you show specific menu according to role , user can only visit that page.

Comment: I know that. I am displaying menu based on the user role only. But in a single app js file I am having all the states (for all users). We can restrict display menu items from the UI, but if user knows the state url for admin or other user roles then he can navigate to the page correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass roles through the data attribute and the check the user access on the $stateChangeStart event. This would off course require you to implement users with user roles.

Pass the role restriction as custom data to state object (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#user-content-attach-custom-data-to-state-objects)

```
$stateProvider
  .state('admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    data: {
      roles: ['ROLE_ADMIN']
    }
  })
```

Then in the .run function do a check on the $stateChangeStart event if current user has said role and if so allow the route change, if not send user to some kinda access denied page (or just prevent state change).

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toStateParams) {
      // Check if current user has group access
      if(!AuthService.userHasRole(toStateParams.roles)) {
         $state.go('accessdenied');
      }
   })
})
```

There would be quite a bit of work off course to get this working. Setting up users/roles/auth etc. Will leave that to you. JHipster (https://jhipster.github.io/) has a pretty solid auth, access, user with user roles implementation. The backend is in Java though. But the Angular implementation is rock solid.

Comment: Yeah, this will work but I am worried about security. I have a question, as we given user role list in JS, Is there any chance user can change that from browser and got access to that view.

Comment: Again, this was just a rough example how you can set user role access for certain routes. In terms of security overall that is a completely different story. The userHasRole call should probably be an isAuthenticated call that would also involve checking the user access roles. This could then be combined with a http interceptor that would reject any HTTP calls where the users doesn't have access (i.e. not logged in or no access in terms of roles). I would really recommend you have a look at JHipster. Pretty solid stuff. And please accept answer if it helped :)

Comment: Actually totally missed you mentioned Spring in your initial question. JHipster uses spring for the backend and allows an app to be scaffolded with regular spring security. Have a look at that and it will take you a long way, or use JHipster :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on JHipster. I will spend some time on it.

Comment: As @perry said, Jhipster has and strong authentication and authorization system using JWT as security mechanisms and a role-based authorization with AngularJS in the frontend and Spring Boot in the backed. I suggest you generate a simple app and check the generated code as a good start about how authentication and authorization process works in Jhipster. This answer is an accepted answer@perry

Answer (score 0):

One way I am exploring is simply putting the various views on the page wrapped in ng-if's and checking the userRole.role(a global value) to determine which state to view.

However, there has to be(or should) be a way to do it relatively easily in UI-Router I would think...

Then again, I wam building this on a sharepoint site, so I don't have to worry about top level access rights as we set those on Sharepoint itself. Anyone who can actualy view the page will be 1 of 5 types of userRoles, I simply have to get the role and then show the proper view based on that role